# ActiveRecord "where" clause for has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in a many-to-many relationship.

A `Capability` model:

```rb
class Capability < ApplicationRecord
  …
end
```

And a `Teammate`:

```rb
class Teammate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teammate_capabilities
  has_many :capabilities, through: :teammate_capabilities
end
```

The join model:

```rb
class TeammateCapability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teammate
  belongs_to :capability
end
```

Now I want to find all teammates who have at least one of a group of capabilities. I tried:

```rb
capabilities = Capability.where(id: [197, 198]) # works
teammates = Teammate.where(capabilities: capabilities) # blows up
```

The second line results in:

```
=> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "capability_id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ROM "teammates" WHERE "teammates"."id" IN (SELECT capability...
```

What did I do wrong? What's the right syntax for my query? I would like a collection of all Teammates with at least Capability 197 or Capability 198.

Comment: Have you looked at using `joins` to [specify conditions on the joined table](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Teammate.joins(:capabilites).where(capabilities: {id: capabilities})`

You need to join the table and then traverse the relationship in the where clause. This should work.